# Primitive notions in first-order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

Are the following primitive notions in first-order logic?

1. $\wedge$ and $\neg$ (if I define all other connectives in terms of these);
2. $\exists$ (if I define $\forall$ in terms of it).

Comment: Yes; $\land$ and $\lnot$ are enough to define all other propositional connectives in classical propositional logic.

Comment: And we can define $\forall$ as $\lnot \exists \lnot$ (again in classical logic).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I know we can define like you mention. But what I’m asking is whether they are *primitive notions* or not.

Comment: They are "primitive" if you start from them to define others. Do you have a different concept of "primitive" ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA can’t we define $\land$ and $\lnot$ via truth tables.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA By primitive, I mean they can be *described* only by axioms. By non-primitive, I mean they can be *defined* via primitives.

Comment: The semantical definition of connectives through truth tables works only for classical logic; for difefrent logics, like e.g. the Intuitionistic ones, we have a different semantics and thus a difefrent "definition" of them.

Comment: Truth tables are just another form of axiom. What is primitive and what is not primitive depends on the choice of the author. having $\wedge$ and $\neg$ as primitives is a common choice. But you could as easily use $\vee$ and $\neg$ as primitives, or just NAND (or NOR).